# How to list exact service name matching using psservice.exe

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am using a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) to get list of services, and if a service is stoppped I want to start the service using `psservice.exe`.

I am able to execute and succeed, however if I have a service names "abc" and "abc:1234" then when I execute my query using psservice it is listing both "abc" and "abc:1234" services. I dont want another service in my output list, I only want the specific name given in the filter.

e.g. `psservice \\server -u test -p XXXX query "abc"`

Please help me to filter/get only the exact matched service name using psservice?

Actual result I am getting:

```
PsService v2.25 - Service information and configuration utility
Copyright (C) 2001-2010 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

SERVICE_NAME: abc:1234
DISPLAY_NAME: abc:1234
Enables the abc:1234 service which allows abc products to run on this computer. If this service is stopped, abc products may not run.
        TYPE              : 10 WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
        STATE             : 4  RUNNING
                               (STOPPABLE,NOT_PAUSABLE,IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE   : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT        : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT         : 0 ms

SERVICE_NAME: abc 
DISPLAY_NAME: abc 
Enables the abc  service which allows abc  products to run on this computer. If this service is stopped, abc  products may not run.
        TYPE              : 10 WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
        STATE             : 4  RUNNING
                               (STOPPABLE,NOT_PAUSABLE,IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE   : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT        : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT         : 0 ms
```

But I am expecting results as below:

```
PsService v2.25 - Service information and configuration utility
Copyright (C) 2001-2010 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

SERVICE_NAME: abc 
DISPLAY_NAME: abc 
Enables the abc  service which allows abc  products to run on this computer. If this service is stopped, abc  products may not run.
        TYPE              : 10 WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
        STATE             : 4  RUNNING
                               (STOPPABLE,NOT_PAUSABLE,IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE   : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT        : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT         : 0 ms
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as you've discovered, `PsService Query abc` will report on all service or display names exactly matching or  beginning with the case insensitive string `abc`. You will therefore need to filter the results later, or perhaps use `WMIC` with `/Node`, `/User`, `/Password` and your service query, e.g. `Service Where "DisplayName='abc'" Get StartMode, State, Status` you could obviously include the `/Output` or `/Append` options with possibly `/Format` .

Comment: Thanks Compo, i will use WMIC and confirm the same. I have a question that my script having multiple goto statements in FOR loop. But after first iteration it is coming out of the script or repeating last goto statement. Any suggestions. I converted my Code to power-shell but there is no GOTO statements in power-shell i believe. please check and suggest.